# bootstrap popover form ( ajax)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am in the middle of implementing a feature.

[image: feature]

objective :

to have a popover form with ajax request .
    [bootstrap popover](http://jsfiddle.net/AFffL/3/)

NOTE : previously i tried to achive the same with the [bootstrap editables](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/)

but due to the fact that I don't want data(entered in popover) to be shown on page . (which editables are for)  .

So ,

with current method (jsfiddle)

ISSUE :

when I am clicking on the popover to enter data inside the from popover disappears.

i am searching for a jquery fix . ( something with event propagation will do )

my code :

```
<div class="box-icon" >
    <div class="popover-markup">
        <a href="#" class="trigger"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a> 
            <div class="head hide">Enter Email<i class="icon-remove" style="margin-left: 120px;"></i></div>
                <div class="content hide">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Type email address">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                </div>
            <div class="footer hide">test</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and my scripts are :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.popover-markup > .trigger').popover({ 
        html : true,
        title: function() {
            return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
        },
        content: function() {
            return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
        }
    });

    // Attach click handler to document
    $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
        $(".popover-markup").popover('hide');
    });

    // Dont hide when I click anything inside #container
    $('.popover-markup').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

Comment: not get jsFiddle link

Comment: goto jsfiddle.net and create your fiddle with your code.

Comment: Should'nt it be `$(".popover-markup > .trigger").popover('hide');` ? Besides that (and the missing `>`, fixed), the code is working just fine (FF 22, Chrome 28, latest jQuery & Bootstrap).